# Need help: My set collection doesn't display all the items I inputted

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, collections, set

I'm working on a problem right now and I couldn't understand why my collection doesn't display my inputs properly and it only displays the last entry. Let me show you my code.

So first off there are 2 JSPs(inputsubjects.jsp and schedule.jsp), 2 Servlets(LE4Servlet1 and LE4Servlet2) and 1 Plain Java class(Subjects.java).

For inputsubjects.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">

        Subject Code: <input type="text" name="inputSC">
        <br><br>
        Description: <input type="text" name="inputDesc">
        <br><br>
        Unit(s): <input type="text" name="inputUnit">
        <br><br>

        <center>
            <input type="SUBMIT" value="Save and Add" formaction="LE4Servlet1">
            <input type="SUBMIT" value="Save and Exit" formaction="LE4Servlet2">
        </center>            
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For schedule.jsp: (for this jsp however,the data should be displayed in table form but I don't know how to create a dynamic table yet so in this code I'm trying to see if my java class works and unfortunately it doesn't.)

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Set"%>
<%@page import="foo.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<%
    Set output1 = (Set)request.getAttribute("output1");
    Iterator it1 = output1.iterator();
    out.println("<br>Subject Code: ");
    while(it1.hasNext())
    {
        out.println(it1.next());
    }

    Set output2 = (Set)request.getAttribute("output2");
    Iterator it2 = output2.iterator();
    out.println("<br>Description: ");
    while(it2.hasNext())
    {
        out.println(it2.next());
    }

    Set output3 = (Set)request.getAttribute("output3");
    Iterator it3 = output3.iterator();
    out.println("<br>Unit(s): ");
    while(it3.hasNext())
    {
        out.println(it3.next());
    }      
%>
</body>
</html>
```

So there are 2 buttons and the Save and Add button takes the inputted data and put the data in a collection only and takes another input while Save and Exit button does the same thing but is used for the last entry and will redirect you to schedule.jsp where it will show the data that you have entered.

For LE4Servlet1 and LE4Servlet2(they have the same code except for the RequestDispatcher):

```
        String inputsc = request.getParameter("inputSC");
        String inputdesc = request.getParameter("inputDesc");
        String inputunit = request.getParameter("inputUnit");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(inputunit);
        Subjects subj = new Subjects(inputsc,x,inputdesc);
        Set isc = subj.getCode(inputsc);
        Set id = subj.getDesc(inputdesc);
        Set iu = subj.getUnit(x);
        request.setAttribute("output1", isc);
        request.setAttribute("output2", id);
        request.setAttribute("output3", iu);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("inputsubjects.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
```

Now here is my code for Subjects.java and where I think the problem lies.

For Subjects.java:

```
public class Subjects 
{
private String code;                 
private int unit;
private String description;

public Subjects(String code, int unit, String description)
{
    this.code = code;
    this.unit = unit;
    this.description = description;
}

public Set getCode(String inputSC)
{ 
    Set code = new HashSet();

    code.add(inputSC);

    return code;
}

public Set getUnit(int inputUnit)
{
    Set unit = new HashSet();

    unit.add(inputUnit);

    return unit;
}

public Set getDesc(String inputDesc)
{
    Set desc = new HashSet();

    desc.add(inputDesc);

    return desc;  
}
```

}

I would really appreciate your help guys since I want to learn a lot about web developing and for now I'm really having problems since I'm still a student. Sorry for the long question :(

Note: Please don't take this question as for me to only pass my assignment but I'm asking this question for me to learn more about web developing since I'm passionate about it and I want to be a web developer someday :)

Note: I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.1 in this project.

Comment: You've provided way too much code, you need to step through with a debugger and identify the location of the problem. 
From a glance though, it looks like you are not adding to the existing Sets, you keep making new Sets each time.

Comment: Sorry I had provided lots of code Roman, I just thought if someone would want to try the code then it's there already. I also thought of that idea but I can't find a solution about it, I've been thinking a lot lately and I thought of adding a counter for it to repeat and doing the add function again and again at a limited number but I don't think it is correct since the JSP should be dynamic.

Comment: I'm on Mobile.. So Can't run this code.. Firstly, In schedule.jsp, store everything in a String then print all at once.. Also, In Subjects.java, You're creating a new HashSet each time.. Send HashSet lines to Constructor.. The get methods should only contain add() method..

Comment: There was a problem in sending the HashSet lines to the Constructor with the get methods containg add() method. I think I cannot use the HashSet that was declared in the constructor in the get methods since they only use local variables. Thanks for answering though! I appreciated! :)

Comment: Hey, That's Wrong. At least code that yourself. Declare **private Set Code, Unit, Desc;** and initialize them in Constructor, then, add() anything in function.

Comment: Hi user388229! I tried to do what you told me but it still doesn't work unfortunately. I still can't find a solution yet.